# Should there be a warning regarding plagiarism in the homework help section

Tags: discussion, homework, help-center

I am concerned that in answering some homework questions one is providing material for the questioner to use to obtain undeserved course credits.

It may be spitting into the wind but I think the Help should remind/warn questioners about college policies on student plagiarism and make them aware that answers on the site will be picked up by plagiarism checkers.

I suppose we should all be vigilant regarding questions that violate the guidelines. What do we do? Flag them in some way?

And should answerers also be warned i.e. do not to feed the wild animals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not a big problem as most homework questions are closed pretty fast and get no answers. Most of them are pretty obvious and they are never edited to make them a valid question.

Homework questions which show some effort (and are thus not off-topic) can be borderline in this respect, but in the end this is something we cannot control. If you see something you find suspicious, flag it.

Comment: OK. Probably better than adding more text people will ignore.